# Numpy add.at not working with masked array

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

I'm trying to sum some numbers in a masked array using `np.add.at` as follows:

```
acc = np.ma.zeros((1,), dtype=np.float64)
arr = np.ma.masked_array([1.,2.,3.,4.,5.], mask=[0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
np.add.at(acc, [0,0,0,0,0], arr)
assert acc[0] == 13
```

This fails however. `add.at` appears to ignore the masking, and `acc[0]` equals 15, not 13 as expected. Should this work as I'm expecting? Is there an `add.at` equivalent in `numpy.ma` I should be using?

Comment: `numpy.ma.add` has no `at` support. I *think* you're stuck just handling the mask yourself.

Comment: `np.add.at(acc, [0,0,0,0], arr.compressed())`?

Comment: @user2357112 :( darn. How can you tell that? Having trouble finding any documentation at all on `numpy.ma.add`.

Comment: `ma` typically does the regular math on the `data` component, and does something else of its own design to the mask.  There may have been too many open issues to implement this 'something else' for the `.at`  method.

Comment: @It_is_Chris interesting idea that does indeed work for the simple example i have posted, but in reality having to modify the indices array in my `at` call wouldn't be ideal

Comment: So you expected it to skip `arr[1]` because it is masked?  A full implementation would have to work with  masks for 3 arrays, `acc`, `arr` and the index. `.at` is intended to give a semi-compiled alternative to an iterative version of unbuffered '+=`. It's not a trivial fix for the ufunc buffering with duplicate indices.

Comment: The `ma` sub class is not a heavily used or maintained part of numpy.  `pandas` has, I think, taken over a lot the tasks that have missing data, like real-world data series.

Comment: @RobAllsopp: I just did `import numpy.ma` and tried `numpy.ma.add.at`, and got an AttributeError.

Comment: @user2357112 well thats one way haha. I guess I was looking for some official documentation that said one way or the other so I could potentially call it a bug, or know it was intentionally not supported and abandon all hope.

Comment: @RobAllsopp Ah I see, but if you already have the mask `mask=[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]` can you just create another masked arr for the indices used in `np.add.at`? something like: `np.add.at(acc, np.ma.masked_array([0,0,0,0,0], mask=arr.mask).compressed(), arr.compressed())`. Just trying to think of some possible workarounds.

Comment: @It_is_Chris I also realized `compressed()` isn't ideal with the multi-dimensional arrays I have in reality.  If my array and mask are something like `[[1.,2.,3.], [1.,2.,3.]]` and `[[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]]`, compressed just flattens the array into `[1,3,1]` , which I also can't really have. My accumulator is only smaller in one dimension, for the rest I think I would need to maintain the shape. Your efforts are nonetheless appreciated!

Comment: Don't expect a numpy dev to quickly add this new feature.  Work out the details for yourself using loops (slow - boohoohoo) or with a clever use of filled/compressed.  And study the `np.core.ma.py` yourself, and learn to be a ma-dev!